# Weird behavior - getting GDT @ inline assembly

Tags: c, inline-assembly

Before I start, all the code mentioned here is running @ ring0 (Kernel mode) - OSX 10.9:

The following function CRASHES:

```
UINT64 GetGdtBase()
{
    UINT64 gdt = 0;
    asm("sgdt %0\n" ::"m"(gdt));
    return gdt >> 16;
}
```

The following function runs FINE:

```
UINT64 GetGdtBase(UINT64* result)
{
    asm("sgdt %0\n" ::"m"(*result));
    *result >>= 16;
    return *result;
}
```

ehm, it looks kinda funny & weird to me but maybe you guys will find something wrong that I do here.

Would love to hear some suggestions.

thanks

Comment: 1. Does the second version run fine in the sense of not crashing, or in the sense of doing what you expect? 2. If I understand `asm ::` correctly, it wants the input address after the second, so the `gdt` or `*result` is an input rather than a result. If so, don't you want a single `:` to indicate a result address?

Comment: Sense of not crashing. the first one crashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In long mode (64-bit code) the `sgdt` instruction stores a 64-bit "linear address of GDT" and a 16-bit "GDT limit". This takes up 10 bytes and will not fit in a UINT64.

For the first version of your code, you'd be trashing the stack. Mostly likely corrupting the function's return address and causing a crash.

For the second version of your code, you'd still be trashing something; but whatever is trashed might not be used anyway.